# gcc4.9 does not call correct template function specialization with msvc140 it is working fine

Tags: c++, boost

I am implementing a new boost::archive and i need special handling for collections.
So I have created template specializations for **boost::serialization::stl::save_collection** and **boost::serialization::load/save_map_collection**, all implementations are inline

With msvc14 everything is working fine.

With gcc49 it always is the original boost implementation of **boost::serialization::stl::save_collection** called.

The **boost::serialization::load/save_map_collection** is working correctly with gcc49 and my specialization is used.

here my declarations:

```
    # pragma once
    #include <boost/config.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/collection_size_type.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/item_version_type.hpp>

    namespace boost{
    namespace serialization {
    namespace stl {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // implementation of serialization for STL containers
    //

    template</*class Archive,*/ class Container>
    inline void save_collection(
        ::boost::archive::my_oarchive & ar,
        const Container &s,
        collection_size_type count)
    {
    .....
    }

    template</*class Archive,*/ class Container>
    inline void save_collection(::boost::archive::my_oarchive & ar, const Container &s)
    {
        // record number of elements
        collection_size_type count(s.size());
        save_collection(ar, s, count);
    }

    } // namespace stl 
    } // namespace serialization
    } // namespace boost
```

I have played around with the include order and removed the #pragma once but still no success!

Any ideas?

Comment: The given code does not contain any template specializations and is far from [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)